# Why am I getting an error when the parameter 'param_distributions' of RandomizedSearchCV is given a List of Dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I can see in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) that the parameter `param_distribution` accepts dict or list of dict. My code here works when I pass a dictionary but I'm getting an error as soon as I pass a list of dictionary.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

breast_cancer = load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(load_breast_cancer().data, columns = breast_cancer.feature_names)
df['target'] = pd.Series(load_breast_cancer().target)
df.head()

Xi = df.iloc[:,:-1]
Yi = df.iloc[:,-1]

x_train1, x_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(Xi, Yi, train_size = 0.9)
dist = [{'C': np.random.uniform(34,89,4)}, {"C": np.random.uniform(2, 16, 5)}]    # {"C": uniform(4, 97)}
rcv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = LogisticRegression(), cv = 5, scoring= 'roc_auc', n_jobs= 5,
                         param_distributions= dist, n_iter = 10)

rcv.fit(x_train1, y_train1)
```

### Output:

*AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)*

*AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'*

My code works fine when I replace this List of Dict with a single dictionary e.g.

```
dist = {'C': np.random.uniform(34,89,45)}

rcv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = LogisticRegression(), cv = 5, scoring= 'roc_auc', n_jobs= 5,
                         param_distributions= dist, n_iter = 20)

rcv.fit(x_train1, y_train1)
```

Output:

```
RandomizedSearchCV(cv=5, error_score='raise-deprecating',
                   estimator=LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None,
                                                dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
                                                intercept_scaling=1,
                                                l1_ratio=None, max_iter=100,
                                                multi_class='warn', n_jobs=None,
                                                penalty='l2', random_state=None,
                                                solver='warn', tol=0.0001,
                                                verbose=0, warm_start=False),
                   iid='warn', n_iter=20, n_jobs=5,
                   param_distributions...
       68.32247988, 53.2886396 , 64.71957325, 53.42115708, 66.06577109,
       54.09200687, 87.22769322, 81.02240252, 55.25783926, 84.31009298,
       71.13884939, 85.74823239, 87.23400718, 54.48527833, 59.49131351,
       63.59157499, 38.9348315 , 51.5738502 , 82.72414647, 75.27901268,
       42.63960409, 40.65314118, 56.97608301, 66.41059041, 58.37528729])},
                   pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', random_state=None, refit=True,
                   return_train_score=False, scoring='roc_auc', verbose=0)
```

Comment: Your code runs well with `sklearn v0.22.2` after correcting for Xi and Yi. What is your version?

Comment: I tried running: ` sklearn.__version__` it says "0.22"

Comment: Please make your code fully reproducible - define `Xi` and `Yi`.

Comment: @desertnaut, I edited my code !

Comment: As @SergeyBushmanov reports, I also cannot reproduce your issue with sklearn `0.22.2`; first code snippet works OK.

Comment: @desertnaut, I just updated my sklearn library to v0.22.2 and re-ran, it worked now with some warning, which I am not able to understand, is it still fine to have those warnings...?

Comment: @desertnaut , I just figured out why those warnings were appearing it was because of the parameter "n_iter = 20", I changed it to default 10. It worked now. Thanks !

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Thanks for letting me know to update the version of the library !

Comment: Cool. I suggest you post it as an answer for others in the future (and accept it after the 2-day period). Good thing you posted a reproducible example ;)

Comment: Sure will do, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works with sklearn's version v0.22.2 as suggested by @SergeyBushmanov.
I also had to adjust the value of `n_iter` parameter to evade the warning messages. Before the parameter was set to 20 as because of that those warnings appeared. Those warnings were legitimate too since, I have two hyperparameter("C") `dist = [{'C': np.random.uniform(34,89,4)}, {"C": np.random.uniform(2, 16, 5)}]`. Now, in total there are 4x5=20 combinations of hyperparameters to be tried. `n_iter` specifies number of combinations to be tried. If `n_iter = 10`, it means out of 20, RandomSearchCV will try on random 10 combinations of the hyperparameter values.